# How can I print this webpage into a pdf file without missing diagrams?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, webpage

I printed [this page](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-common-software-architectural-patterns-in-a-nutshell-a0b47a1e9013) into a PDF file, by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in chrome browser, or command

```
google-chrome --headless --print-to-pdf https://towardsdatascience.com/10-common-software-architectural-patterns-in-a-nutshell-a0b47a1e9013
```

But the PDF file doesn't have the diagrams in the webpage, e.g.

[image]

I was wondering what I can do about the problem? Alternatively, what are some other ways which can print the whole webpage into a pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

I use a screen capture software that has a free version. I'm not sure about the rules of providing links to products, so will not put it in, however there are several out there. Windows also has a builtin screenshot using the Print Screen button and it will save the entire screen to a jpg. That can then be converted to a pdf.

BTW: I was able to print that to a pdf using the process that you posted. It did take some time for the page to load and the diagram seemed to be the last item. I waited for it to load fully before printing, I'm not sure if that made a difference.

Comment: Thanks. Does `google-chrome --headless --print-to-pdf` work for you?

Comment: sorry, I don't use Chrome that way so unable to answer